# Requirement not found when specifying PyPi dependencies on Dataflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform

I am trying to run some preprocessing using `apache-beam (v2.15.0)` and `tensorflow-transform (v0.15.0)` with `python 3.6`. When I run it locally on my Mac, it works fine, however, when I try to run it via dataflow I keep getting what I think to be dependency errors.

These errors originate from the `requirements.txt` file that is required when using dataflow so that it knows what additional python packages it needs to install.

My `requirements.txt` file contains just `tensorflow-transform`

I thought that this would be simple, since it works without any problems on my laptop. However, the error I get when trying to run it via dataflow is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
tensorflow-metadata<0.15,>=0.14 (from tensorflow-transform->-r 
requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.6.0, 0.9.0, 0.12.1)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for 
tensorflow-metadata<0.15,>=0.14 (from tensorflow-transform->-r 
requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/649#issuecomment-534239863 ?